How to Prevent Google Maps ImageMapType Overlay from Overloading and Freezing During Rapid Zooming in React
I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API with React and TypeScript to add a custom ImageMapType overlay with dynamically generated tiles to a map. My application retrieves tile URLs through the getTileUrl() function where I provide it a URL given to me by an Earth Engine script with getMap().
The problem arises when I rapidly zoom in and out, the network tab shows a surge of tile requests. This sometimes results in HTTP 429 errors ("Too Many Requests"), and in severe cases, the entire browser tab freezes, forcing a full restart.
Here's how I'm currently adding the ImageMapType overlay to the map:
const addOverlay = (url: string, polygonId: number) => {
  if (!map) return;

  const overlayMapParams = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: (coord: google.maps.Point, zoom: number) => {
      // Attempts to throttle during active zooming
      if (isZooming) {
        return ''; // Skip tile requests when zooming
      }
      return url
        .replace('{x}', coord.x.toString())
        .replace('{y}', coord.y.toString())
        .replace('{z}', zoom.toString());
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity: 0.8,
    name: 'Abundance',
  });

  map.overlayMapTypes.push(overlayMapParams);
};

The issue seems related to the queuing of tile requests when zooming in/out rapidly.
I found an old discussion in 2011 about tiles not being cancelled efficiently during rapid zooming, leading to overloads: https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3/c/dCUCZ7vi7Rs
but it didn't really help.
Is there an optimal way to manage or throttle getTileUrl calls during rapid zooms to avoid flooding requests?
Is there a way to pause the rendering of new tiles while the map is zooming and resume when the zoom stops?
Are there best practices or patterns in React and TypeScript for handling ImageMapType overlays more efficiently? The idea is to have multiple different polygons with their own respective overlays on the map simultaneously so I am open to any suggestions if using overlays is not the right idea.
I've tried a few approaches, including throttling requests and managing state during map events, but I'm can't seem to prevent overlays from overloading when zooming quickly.
One idea is to somehow find a way to make getTileUrl a dynamic function that would check if the map is zooming and if so returning '' but I struggle to find a way.
Any insights or examples on how to handle this situation more effectively would be greatly appreciated!

Is it possible for you provide a codepen or something that the community can check?
